# Traefik docker(compose), multiple host in label. Let is serve different ssl certs

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik

I have a dev setup that for my needs right now. I only want serve multiple self signed ssl cert. I added a ca to my keychain(macOS), and use that ca to sign my own cert for every test domain. I'm using docker-compose with traefik as proxy manager and alemp stack for wordpress development.
I can now generate wildcards certs for {domain}.test and  www.{domain}.test. But i have some multisites thats using more than 1 domain. It's working on http on the same lemp stack but cant figure it out how to use multiple cert on traefik
My configs:

-- lemp stack (php and other services not included)

```
 version: '3.7'
    services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-nginx
        volumes:
          - "./nginx/:/etc/nginx/templates/"
          - ./src:/var/www/html:rw,cached
        environment:
          - "NGINX_ENVSUBST_TEMPLATE_SUFFIX=.conf"
        depends_on:
          - app
        networks:
          - default
          - traefik
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN}`)${DOMAIN_ADDITIONAL} || Host(`${DOMAIN2}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN2}`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.services.${APP_NAME}.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
        restart: always
```

-- My traefik proxy

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: traefik
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.4
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      - --providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/dynamic
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "192.168.255.1:80:80"
      - "192.168.255.1:443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "192.168.255.1:8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./traefik/dynamic/dynamic.yaml:/etc/traefik/dynamic/dyn.yaml
      - ./traefik/certs:/etc/traefik/certs:ro


networks:
  default:
    name: traefik_proxy
    external: false
```

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: for local development i started to use https://github.com/bjornsnoen/minica-api and thats works very well. For production the acme feature that's built into traefik